# Django Test "database table is locked"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my Django project, I have a view that when a user posts a zip file, it will respond immediately back and then process the data in the background with the help of threading. The view works fine in normal test, but when I run the Django's test it fails with a `database table is locked` error. Currently, I'm using default SQLite database and I know if I switch to another database this problem may be solved but I'm seeking an answer for the current setup. I trimmed the code for simplicity.

It seems that the problem is with writing in `DeviceReportModel` table. But I'm not sure why `TestDeviceReport` accessing it.

`Model.py`:

```
class DeviceReportModel(models.Model):
    device_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    report_file = models.FileField(upload_to="DeviceReport")
    device_datas = models.ManyToManyField(DeviceDataReportModel)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

`Serializers.py`:

```
class DeviceReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceReportModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('created_time', 'ip', 'device_datas')
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue

class DeviceReportHandler:
    ReportQueue = Queue()

    @staticmethod
    def save_datas(device_object, request_ip, b64datas):
        device_data_models = []
        # ...
        # process device_data_models
        # this will take some time
        time.sleep(10)
        return device_data_models

    @classmethod
    def Check(cls):
        while(True):
            if not cls.ReportQueue.empty():
                report = cls.ReportQueue.get()
                # ...
                report_model = DeviceReportModel(
                    device_id=report['device_object'], ip=report['request_ip'])
                # THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
                report_model.report_file.save(
                    "Report_{}.txt.gz".format(timezone.now()), ContentFile(report['report_data']))

                device_data_models = cls.save_datas(
                    report['device_object'], report['request_ip'], 'SomeData')
                report_model.device_datas.set(device_data_models)
                report_model.save()
                print("Report Handle Done")
            time.sleep(.1)

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=cls.Check)
        thr.daemon = True
        thr.start()


class DeviceReportView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = DeviceReportModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceReportSerializer
    DeviceReportHandler.run()

    def post(self, request):
        # ...
        report = {
            'device_object': 1,
            'request_ip': '0.0.0.0',
            'report_data': b'Some report plain data',
        }
        # add request to ReportQueue
        DeviceReportHandler.ReportQueue.put(report)
        return Response("OK", status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`tests.py`:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import time

class TestDeviceReport(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # add a new test device for other tests
        pass

    def generate_device_data(self):
        # generate fake device data
        return ""

    def test_Report(self):
        # generate device data
        device_data = ''
        for i in range(10):
            device_data += self.generate_device_data() + '\n'

        buf = BytesIO()
        compressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode="wb")
        compressed.write(device_data.encode())
        compressed.close()
        b64data = base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue()).decode()
        data = {
            "device_id": 1,
            "report_data": b64data
        }
        response = self.client.post(
            '/device/reports/', data=data, format='json')
        print(response.status_code, response.content)

    def tearDown(self):
        # put some sleep to check whether the data has been processed
        # see "Report Handle Done"
        time.sleep(10)
```

And here is error log:

```
(myDjangoEnv) python manage.py test deviceApp.tests.tests.TestDeviceReport
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
201 b'"OK"'
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database table is locked

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<project_path>\deviceApp\views.py", line 303, in Check
    "Report_{}.txt.gz".format(timezone.now()), ContentFile(report['report_data']))
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 93, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database table is locked

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 10.023s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Database is locked errors**

SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can’t support a high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.

Python’s SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.

If you’re getting this error, you can solve it by:

Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite becomes too “lite” for real-world applications, and these sorts of concurrency errors indicate you’ve reached that point.

Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived.

Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    # ...
    'timeout': 20,
    # ...
}
```

This will make SQLite wait a bit longer before throwing “database is locked” errors; it won’t really do anything to solve them.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errorsoption

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. It seems that my problem is with `table is locked` rather than `database is locked`.

Comment: I have set the timeout to 500 seconds. But I get a database is locked error after about 1 second already. Is it a problem if multiples threads wait at the same time for the database?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `django.test.TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`

Comment: `TestCase` actually inherited `TransactionTestCase`

Comment: @DavidPiao, TestCase does extra stuff and that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TestCase uses a transaction to wrap the unit test, ensuring a consistent database configuration for all tests.

TransactionTestCase (weirdly named) means "a test case for testing with transactions). There is no transaction, so other threads/processes won't have to worry about being locked out. Of course the database state isn't as easily rolled back, but Django uses a "serialized_rollback" to serialize the database an restore it (via JSON), which is obviously slower than transactions.